# Installer from NSIS tutorial wrote to wrong user's desktop

Tags: nsis

I am trying to set up one of the installers from the NSIS tutorials. The installer simply writes a text file to the desktop that says "Hello world!". The installer script reads as follows:

```
# declare name of installer file
Outfile "hello world.exe"
 
# open section
Section
 
# create a popup box, with an OK button and some text
MessageBox MB_OK "Now We are Creating Hello_world.txt at Desktop!"
 
/* open an output file called "Hello_world.txt", 
on the desktop in write mode. This file does not need to exist 
before script is compiled and run */
 
FileOpen $0 "$DESKTOP\Hello_world.txt" w
 
# write the string "hello world!" to the output file
FileWrite $0 "hello world!"
 
# close the file
FileClose $0
# Show Success message.
MessageBox MB_OK "Hello_world.txt has been created successfully at Desktop!"
 
 
# end the section
SectionEnd
```

The issue I encountered is that the file did not write to the desktop. After poking around for a few minutes I was able to find the file on the desktop of the Admin account on my computer instead of the current user. What do I need to do to configure NSIS to use the currently logged in user and not the Admin account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `RequestExecutionLevel User` to your script, this will tell Windows that you don't need UAC elevation.

When a non-admin user UAC elevates a new process, it will run as the admin user used in the UAC dialog.